# The Cauchy problem for a higher order differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, cauchy-problem

I need to solve the Cauchy problem for a differential equation:
$$yy''x^2+3yy'x+y^2=(y'x+y)^2(1-y'x^2-yx),\ y(1)=2,\ y'(1)=0$$

I solved this equation:
$$Let\ x=e^t,\ y=ze^{-t},\ y'=e^{-2t}(z'-z),\ y''=e^{-3t}(z''-3z'+2z)$$
$$=>zz''-(z')^2+(z')^3=0$$
$$Let\ z'=p, z''=pp'$$
$$=>zp'=p-p^2$$
$$\int \frac{dp}{p-p^2}=\int \frac{dz}{z}$$
$$\frac{p}{1-p}=zC$$
$$z'=p=\frac{zC}{zC+1}=\frac{z}{C+z}$$

What should I do next? How can I solve the Cauchy problem?

Answer (score 1):

So you set $y(e^t)=z(t)e^{-t}$ or $z(\ln x)=xy(x)$. Then indeed
\begin{align}
z'(t)&=e^{2t}y'(e^t)+e^ty(e^t)=x(xy(x))'\\
z''(t)&=e^{3t}y''(e^t)+3e^{2t}y'(e^t)+e^ty(e^t)\\
&=x(x^2y''(x)+3xy'(x)+y(x))\\
&=\frac{x}{y}\left((xy(x))'\right)^2(1-x(xy(x))')\\
&=\frac{z'(t)^2(1-z'(t))}{z(t)}
\end{align}
This can then be separated into integrable terms, as you did indirectly,
\begin{align}
\frac{z''}{z'(1-z')}=\frac{z'}{z}\\
\frac{z'}{1-z'}=Cz\implies z'=\frac{Cz}{1+Cz}
\end{align}
Now apply again separation-of-variables to get
$$\begin{align}
\frac{z'}{Cz}=1-z'\implies \frac{\ln|z|}{C}+z=t+D.
\end{align}$$
Apply the initial conditions to determine the constants, $z(0)=y(1)=2$, $z'(0)=y'(1)+y(1)=2$ which gives $C=-1$ and then $D=2-\ln(2)$. You can semi-formally solve this by applying the Lambert-W function,
$$
ze^{-z}=e^{-t-2+\ln 2}\iff -ze^{-z}=-2e^{-t-2}\implies z=-W_{-1}(-2e^{-t-2})
$$